# CMB2 Post Search Field displays/repeats initial post if left empty

Tags: plugins, metabox

I'm using CMB2 and the CMB2 Post Search Field to create a one-to-many link between different types of posts (including custom post types), with the post search field in a repeatable metabox group, so that each connected post has some text to provide context to the connection. I've got this working okay - except if a post doesn't have any connected posts. If the field/group is left empty, my post/page template repeats the main post content in place of the expected connected post.

Setting up my metabox:

```
function gwl_register_post_connection_metabox() {
$prefix = 'gwl_collection_post_connection_';

$cmb_group = new_cmb2_box( array(
    'id'           => $prefix . 'metabox',
    'title'        => __( 'Connected posts', 'gwl-cd' ),
    'object_types' => array( 'post','page','gwl_exhibition' ), 
) );

$group_field_id = $cmb_group->add_field( array(
    'id'          => $prefix . 'group',
    'type'        => 'group',
    'description' => __( 'You can connect different collection items and names, as well as posts and other content from across the website.', 'gwl-cd' ),
    'options'     => array(
        'group_title'   => __( 'Connected post {#}', 'gwl-cd' ), 
        'add_button'    => __( 'Add another post', 'gwl-cd' ),
        'remove_button' => __( 'Remove post', 'gwl-cd' ),
        'sortable'      => true, 
    ),
) );

$cmb_group->add_group_field( $group_field_id, array(
    'name'        => __( 'Connected Post', 'gwl-cd' ),
    'description' => __( 'Select an item, name or post by entering the post ID, or click on the search symbol to find a post', 'gwl-cd' ),
    'id'          => $prefix . 'related_post',
    'type'        => 'post_search_text', 
    'post_type'   => array( 'post','page','gwl_exhibition','gwl_name','gwl_item' ), 
    'select_type' => 'radio',
    'select_behavior' => 'replace',
) );

$cmb_group->add_group_field( $group_field_id, array(
    'name'        => __( 'Context', 'gwl-cd' ),
    'description' => __( 'How does this collection item or other post relate to the main article?', 'gwl-cd' ),
    'id'          => $prefix . 'context',
    'type'    => 'wysiwyg',
    'options' => array(
        'media_buttons' => false, // hide insert/upload button(s) << TBD
        'textarea_rows' => get_option('default_post_edit_rows', 6), 
    ),
) );

}
```

Displaying the connected posts:

```
function gwl_output_connections( $gwl_collection_post_connection_group ) {

$connections = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'gwl_collection_post_connection_group', true );

if ( ! empty( $connections ) ) {

    foreach ( (array) $connections as $key => $connection ) {

        $relpost = $desc = '';

        if ( isset( $connection['gwl_collection_post_connection_related_post'] ) ) 
            $relpost = esc_html( $connection['gwl_collection_post_connection_related_post'] );

        if ( isset( $connection['gwl_collection_post_connection_context'] ) )
            $desc = wpautop( $connection['gwl_collection_post_connection_context'] );

        echo '<div class="connected-post"><h3><a href="';
        echo get_permalink( $relpost );
        echo '">';
        echo get_the_title( $relpost );
        echo '</a></h3> <p>';
        echo get_the_excerpt( $relpost );
        echo '</p><p>';
        echo $desc;
        echo '</p></div>';
    }
}

else {
    echo '<p>There are no connected posts.</p>';
}

}
```

(I've tried variations on the !empty check, as well as isset, but can't get that last line to display correctly when there's no connected post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think that I've sorted this myself by looking again at the isset check. Instead of

```
if ( ! empty( $connections ) ) {
```

I've put:

```
if ( isset( $connections[0]['gwl_collection_item_name_connection_related_post'] ) ) {
```

and so far this seems to be working. (I think the issue arises because the CMB2 group saves an empty array in the meta_value column, so $connections isn't empty/ is set, and because the array doesn't have a value for the post id, it then pulls in the id of the initial post - but I'm not sure if my understanding of this is correct)